# Integrating groovy and Robot Framework

Tags: groovy, robotframework

Can anyone tell me how to import Groovy test libraries into robot framework?

I'm using robot framework for test library written in Groovy (filename is `ProxyTest.groovy`). While trying to run the test suite I'm getting the following error:

```
[ ERROR ] Invalid syntax in file 'c:\users\admin\desktop\proxy1\proxy.html' in table 'Setting': Importing test library 'ProxyTest' failed: ImportError: No module named ProxyTest
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean a bit more? Are you talking about the `java.awt.Robot` class in Java? http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

Comment: I'm Using robot framework for test library written in GROOVY(File name is ProxyTest.groovy). While trying to run the test suite I'm getting following error: [ ERROR ] Invalid syntax in file 'c:\users\admin\desktop\proxy1\proxy.html' in table 'Setting': Importing test library 'ProxyTest' failed: ImportError: No module named ProxyTest

Comment: Shouldn't all this info (the full exception, how you are running things, etc) go in the question?

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile the groovy source code to .class files, make them available in CLASSPATH, start Robot Framework with `jybot` and import the library like this

```
| Library | package.name.ClassName |
```

Answer (score 0):

This trick won't work. This problem appears because Robot framework **doesn't compile** Groovy or Java sources while executing scenarios. That's why you need to put **compiled groovy bytecode** into class path and put a full qualified class name instead of ProxyTest.groovy

If you use maven to build your project then you can use robotframework-maven-plugin that will compile your code and execute scenarios right after that. There is a [quick tutorial](http://releasecomplete.com/quick-start-with-robot-framework-for-java-projects/) of how to setup your Java (or Groovy) project to run scenarios from Eclipse or command line.